# How to understand if (name in {}) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I encounter a js function snippet, list as follows

```
each = function(obj, fun) {
    if (typeof fun != "function") {
        return obj
    }
    if (obj) {
        var return_value;
        if (obj.length === undefined) {
            for (var name in obj) {
                if (name in {}) { // how to undertand this line, what's purpose?
                    continue
                }
                return_value = fun.call(obj[name], obj[name], name);
                if (return_value == "break") {
                    break
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0,
            length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
                return_value = fun.call(obj[i], obj[i], i);
                if (return_value == "break") {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return obj
};
```

Thanks for your answer:)

Comment: It's a good question. Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 4):

What it's doing is seeing if that property name exists in a blank object. So for instance, it will filter out `toString` (on implementations that aren't buggy about `toString` and `in`; IE is).

It may be an attempt to work around people adding things to the `Object.prototype` (which is a very, very bad idea).  For instance:

```
Object.prototype.foo = "bar";    // <== VERY BAD IDEA
alert({}.foo); // alerts "bar"

function Thingy(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
Thingy.prototype.x = 42;

var t = new Thingy(1, 2);
```

If I want to copy `t`, including its inherited `x` property from `Thingy` but **not** including the `foo` property it inherits from `Object`, I could use that `if (name in {})` to skip those.

Mind you, it's not a very smart way to do that, as it will fail if I do this:

```
var t = new Thingy(1, 2);
t.foo = "charlie";
```

Now `t` has its *own* `foo`, which presumably I would have wanted to copy.

A more thorough check would be:

```
dest = {};
blank = {}; // No need to recreate it on every iteration
for (name in src) {
    if (src.hasOwnProperty(name) || !(name in blank)) {
        dest[name] = src[name];
    }
}
```

That will only filter out ones that are inherited, or at least might be inherited, from `Object`. But even *that's* flawed; what if it inherits a value for the property, but not the value from `Object` (e.g., something in the middle — `Thingy` perhaps — has overridden `Object`'s default)?

So you may want to refactor this code you've inherited, probably in terms of using `hasOwnProperty` and making sure that nothing anywhere in your application puts things on `Object.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

> In is a special operator that returns
>   true if the specified property is in
>   the specified object.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/in_Operator

Every object, including {}, inherits properties from Object.prototype. The `if` here makes the loop continue if `name` is one of those inherited properties.

Example: `console.log('toString' in {});` logs `true`. `console.log('customProperty' in {});` logs false.

Answer (score 1):

The [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/in_Operator) returns true if there is a property in the second operand with the identifier of the first operant, and false otherwise. So `name in {}` checks whether there is a property with the name of the value of `name`.

This probably seems odd as `{}` does not seem to have any properties. But a plain object inherits some the properties from *Object.prototype*. So `"toString" in {}` returns true as there is `Object.prototype.toString`. There is also the `hasOwnProperty` method inherited from `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` that can be used instead.